# Show that $α$ is a root of multiplicity $≥ \min (m_1, m_2)$ of $f_1 (x) g_1 (x) + f_2 (x) g_2 (x)$ where $g_1$, $g_2$ are any two polynomials.

Tags: polynomials, minimal-polynomials

Suppose that $α$ is a root of multiplicity $m_1$ of $f_1$ and that $α$ is a root of multiplicity $m_2$ of $f_2$. Show that $α$ is a root of multiplicity $≥ \min (m_1, m_2)$ of $f_1 (x) g_1 (x) + f_2 (x) g_2 (x)$ where $g_1$, $g_2$ are any two polynomials.

Hi, I have been stuck with this problem and I have no idea/clue to how to start/prove it.

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Write $f_i(X)=(X-\alpha)^mh_i(X)$.

Comment: Can't seem to get the point ):

Comment: I only started to see polynomials